# Lua:создать переменную и сохранить ее в файл

Tags: c++, c, lua

Как в `Lua` изменить переменную и сохранить ее в файл? Есть файл `script.lua`:

```
hello = "nothing"
```

Мне надо чтобы программа не только изменила переменную, но и сохранила ее в файл. То есть после выполнения программы, он должен выглядеть так:

```
hello = "something",
```

Comment: имя для скрипта ничего не значит. содавай таблицу - это проще чем выцеплять имя переменной из исходника

Comment: Можно повесить __newindex на таблицу глобальных переменных _G и отлавливать все создаваемые глобальные переменные (будет доступно имя переменной и её значение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В книге "Programming in lua" есть раздел глава 12. Data Files and Persistence.
Пример сериализации разных типов в разделе 12.2 Serialization

Comment: Спасибо! Вот ссылка на этот кусок: http://www.lua.org/pil/12.1.2.html

Comment: Но мне не совсем это нужно. Мне надо, чтоб когда я изменил переменную из c++, я мог сохранить эти изменения в файл.

Comment: Тогда вам надо делать как писал выше  Egor Skriptunoff. В той же книге ище пример как такое.  13.4 Table-Access Metamethods. Там есть раздел Tracking table accesses  http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html